# sass/scss in ES6 without node or webpack?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sass

I want to turn some scss code into css code in browser without any server interaction, and I don't want to use the tricks like webpack or browserify? I wonder if there's any pure ES6 version of sass/scss so my code can be like this:

```html
<script type="module">
  import sass from 'path/to/sass.js'; // or sass.mjs
</script>
```

Comment: There is noting ES6 about the task. ES6+ is not related to SCSS - these are two completely different things. At best, you can load the SCSS code, compile it in the browser, then insert it into the document. But that's not an ES6 trick. You could do it with any version of JS, as long as there is a library that can do it in the browser.

Comment: @VLAZ you mentioned `compile it in the browser`, how?

Comment: @VLAZ guess you misunderstood my question. Think about I am making an online scss to css converter. I don't need to insert anything to the document.

Comment: In short: this is not likely. The JS tools for converting are based on NodeJS, and require system dependencies like libsass and gyp depending on the version. I think implementations exist in other languages besides JS, but none that can run in the browser natively.

Comment: @Derek I found an npm package called `sass.js`. It seems to do the job. But I am not sure how well it is/will be compatible with the latest version of sass/scss.

Comment: @QianChen "*Think about I am making an online scss to css converter. I don't need to insert anything to the document.*" in that case, same steps but without inserting into the document. Find a library that can do it in the browser, use the library to compile the code in the browser.

Comment: Instead of repeatedly saying I don't understand, feel free to clarify. I do not see how any of what you asked for is in any way related to specifically ES6+ features, rather than just JavaScript. I've put forward what I think the flaw in the question is, to which you've simply said "no" multiple times without in any way explaining yourself. If you share how I'm wrong in this regard, then I might do something about it. Until then I can just say that - no, ES6+ does not have anything to do with what you're asking. At best, it seems like a library request. If it's not, surely you can explain why.